# Async + Axios - Rate control

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, axios

I am currently sending a `GET` request to an API using promises 200 times. Not surprisingly, there is a max number of connections allowed within such a short time span.

I am using `axios` to do this:

```
const memberPromises = members.map(member => axios.get(`players/%23${member.tag}`))

axios.all().then().catch() // etc
```

..where members can be up to 200 elements.

There doesn't seem a way to rate-control these requests natively within `axios`, but how would I use `async`'s (or another library if there is better) `queue` method with a `concurrent` parameter to limit the number of simultaneous requests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

map the members to promises, resolve the promise after a timeout

```
let RATE_LIMIT_BASE = 100; //100ms separation

let promises = members.map((member, idx) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(
            () =>
                axios
                    .get(`players/%23${member.tag}`)
                    .then(res => resolve(res))
                    .catch(err => reject(err)),
            RATE_LIMIT_BASE * idx
        );
    });
});

Promise.all(promises).then().catch(); // etc;
```

In comment, as marvel308 said,

> this could fail in certain cases, since setTimeout just guarantees
>   that the code will execute atleast 100ms after setTimeout is called,
>   they could still queue up in the event queue in case some CPU
>   intensive task was blocking the call stack

Thanks marvel308 for the advise

Comment: I was about to post the same, I think this would work well

Comment: this could fail in certain cases, since setTimeout just guarantees that the code will execute atleast 100ms after setTimeout is called, they could still queue up in the event queue in case some CPU intensive task was blocking the call stack

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this doesn't seem to actually be spacing out the requests. I still get a 429 error status code.

Comment: The answer has been updated, as axios request would not send if its `.then` is not called.

Comment: I'm sorry for not understanding, but .all() can't be called on .map()? I've also tried setting the member.map(...) as a variable and then calling Promise.all(variable) but then i get an array of undefined.

Comment: Thank you again. The part I'm not understanding is that Promise.all() doesn't actually seem to be waiting for the timeout. It returns straight away.Which means that all the elements in returned by Promise.all() are undefined as they haven't allowed the 200x100ms separations...

Comment: Figured it out, you need to return the `new Promise`. If you could edit your answer I'll then accept. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks GarethPrice

Answer (score 1):

```
const axios = require('axios');
const axiosThrottle = require('axios-throttle'); 
//pass axios object and value of the delay between requests in ms
axiosThrottle.init(axios,200)
const options = {
  method: 'GET',
};
const promises = [];
const responseInterceptor = response => {
  console.log(response.data);
  return response;
};

//add interceptor to work with each response seperately when it is resolved
axios.interceptors.response.use(responseInterceptor, error => {
  return Promise.reject(error);
});

for (let index = 0; index < members.length; index++) {
  options.url = `http://yourapiurl/players/%23${member.tag}`;
  promises.push(axiosThrottle.getRequestPromise(options, index));
}

//run when all promises are resolved
axios.all(promises).then(responses => {
  console.log(responses.length);
});
```

https://github.com/arekgotfryd/axios-throttle